# Generating a boxplot with slightly darker lines then the fill color

Tags: r, ggplot2, rgb

To generate less distracting boxplots it would be nice to have a similar color scale for `fill` and `color`. 
How can I achieve this without guesswork?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Predefined colors (scale_*_manual)

### Simple solution using `colorspace::darken()`

This is the easiest solution I guess:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(colorspace)

hex_colors = c(
  setosa = "#80adf7", 
  versicolor = "#96ef8f", 
  virginica = "#f4a1df")

g = ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length, fill = Species, color = Species))
g + geom_boxplot() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = hex_colors) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = darken(hex_colors, amount = 0.3))
```

### Manually calculating the colors

If you want to have more control, you can convert the HEX to RGB and decrease all values of red, green and blue a bit.
You could also convert it to HSV and play easier with hue, saturation, and the luminosity value by adding `rgb2hsv` to the pipelne and calling `hsv` instead of `rgb`at the end.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)

hex_colors = c(
  setosa = "#80adf7", 
  versicolor = "#96ef8f", 
  virginica = "#f4a1df")

dark_colors = hex_colors %>% 
  col2rgb %>% #convert HEX colors to RGB Matrix
  "*"(0.7) %>% # make each component "darker"
  apply(2, lift_dv(rgb, maxColorValue = 255)) # Convert each column to HEX again

g = ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length, fill = Species, color = Species))
g + geom_boxplot() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = hex_colors) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = dark_colors)
```

**Both** approaches lead to the following result:

[image: Boxplots]

## Automatic colors (scale_*_discrete)

`scale_*_discrete` works with the HSL color space. We can just define the luminance manually.

```
library(ggplot2)
g = ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length, fill = Species, color = Species))
g + geom_boxplot() + 
  scale_fill_discrete(l = 70) + # a bit brighter
  scale_color_discrete(l = 50) # a bit darker
```

[image: boxplot 2]

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is simply to pass `alpha()` to `scale_FOO_manual`. With it we only need to specify wanted `alpha` and color values:

```
library(ggplot2)

color <- c("red", "blue", "green")
alpha_color <- 1
alpha_fill <- 0.2

ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length, fill = Species, color = Species)) +
  geom_boxplot() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = alpha(color, alpha_fill)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = alpha(color, alpha_color))
```

[image]

Comment: I like the simplicity of this answer. However, IMHO the result is visually more cluttered, now that grid is visible through the filling. This gives me the idea that you could just write a `darken()` function. Would look even nicer to read.

Comment: @jakob-r That’s true! However it depends on theme. If it’s some minimal theme then background is not an issue